# Spring Boot Kafka Multiple Consumers with different properties configuration using appication.yml/properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have seen examples where we have a java configuration class and we define multiple `KafkaListenerContainer` and pass the required `containerType` to `@kafkaListener`. But i am exploring if there are any ways to achieve the same using Spring Boot auto Kafka configuration via appication.yml/properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; Boot will only auto-configure one set of infrastructure; if you need multiple, you need to define them as beans.

However, with recent versions (since 2.3.4), you can add a listener container customizer to the factory so you can customize each listener container, even though they are created by the same factory; some properties can also be overridden on the `@KafkaListener` annotation itself.

Example:

```java
@Component
class Customizer {

    public Customizer(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> factory) {
        factory.setContainerCustomizer(container -> {
            if (container.getContainerProperties().getGroupId().equals("slowGroup")) {
                container.getContainerProperties().setIdleBetweenPolls(60_000);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I have defined `spring.kafka.listener.type=batch` in my application.properties and tried to override as `@KafkaListener(properties="spring.kafka.listener.type:single"`). But this doesn't work and i am still getting kafka records in batches. Any inputs as where am i going wrong? @GaryRussell

Comment: No; those properties are `Kafka Consumer Properties` only. Unfortunately, the listener type (Batch Vs. Single) is not something you can override; because that determines the type of `KafkaListener` to create; it's not a property of the listener or container, it defines the complete listener type that the factory creates. You still need two factories for that property. I'll see if I can come up with a work-around but, for now, you need 2 factories.