# Why 2 Kafka consumers in Springboot are referring to the same Kafka Broker?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to launch two consumer instances of Kafka from my SpringBoot application. The 2 Kafka consumers listen to 2 different Kafka Brokers (`localhost:9092 and localhost:9093`). Both the consumers have the same topic name and group id. However, only both the consumers are listening to the same instance. What I am doing wrong?

```
application.yml

spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      instance1:
        bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      instance2:
        bootstrap-servers: localhost:9093
      enable-auto-commit: true
      auto-commit-interval: 3000
      auto-offset-reset: latest
      topic: my-topic
      group-id: my-topic-group

KafkaListener.java

public class KafkaListener {
@org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener(id = "instance1", groupId = "${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}", topics = "${spring.kafka.consumer.topic}")
public void consume(String message) {
    // some logging here
}

@org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener(id = "instance2", groupId = "${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}", topics = "${spring.kafka.consumer.topic}", containerFactory = "listenerContainer2Factory")
public void consume(ConsumerRecord record) {
    // some logging here
}
```

}

```
KafkaConfig.java

@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> container1Factory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        Map<String, Object> container1ConsumerProperties = kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties();
        container1ConsumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        container1ConsumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(container1ConsumerProperties);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> listenerContainer1Factory(
            KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(container1Factory(kafkaProperties));
        return factory;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> container2Factory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        Map<String, Object> container2ConsumerProperties = kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties();
        container2ConsumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        container2ConsumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(container2ConsumerProperties);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> listenerContainer2Factory(
            KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(container2Factory(kafkaProperties));
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us, please, from where did you take that syntax for `instance1` etc. configuration style? It is really not what Spring Boot does with its auto-configuration. Your problem that Spring Boot doesn't see those nested properties and just falls back to the default one which is (unlikely for you) is `localhost:9092`.

Comment: @ArtemBilan In Springboot instance1 and instance2 are auto suggested if you go by spring.kafka.consumer

Comment: @ArtemBilan Although what you are suggesting is correct as I see in the console that [Consumer clientId=consumer-my-test-group-1, groupId=my-test-group]  is being printed twice

Comment: @ArtemBilan For the KafkaConfig part I followed this tutorial:
https://howtodoinjava.com/kafka/multiple-consumers-example/

Answer (score 2):

This answer gave me the clue as to where I am going wrong. **[No; Boot will only auto-configure one set of infrastructure; if you need multiple, you need to define them as beans.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64467337/3300911)**

I added the bootstrap details in the bean initialization as below:

```
container1ConsumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
```

and for container2:

```
container2ConsumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9093");
```